# F# Is there a Async.Sequential to match Async.Parallel?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

F# has `Async.Parallel` with type signature `seq<Async<'a>> -> Async<'a list>`, which will take a seq of Async types, prep them to run in parallel, and output a single Async.

I was wondering if there is a similar `Async.Sequential` which has the same type signature, but runs each item in sequence one after the other? I feel like I must be missing something obvious?

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
async {
    let! results =
        myItems
        |> List.map myAsynchronousOperation
        |> Async.Sequential

    ... do something with results
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of F# 4.7 and FSharp.Core 4.7 `Async.Sequential` is now available "out-of-the-box".

Announcement: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-4-7/

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/897afd3dad3bfe58a0495713e99a8094098c18c5/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L1282

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's one built in, but should be trivial to write your own:

```
let sequential s = async {
    let results = ResizeArray()
    for a in s do
        let! result = a
        results.Add(result)
    return List.ofSeq results
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Evaluating the items in a `seq<Async<'a>>` in-order and returning a list is effectively just a `foldBack` on the sequence where you want to evaluate the `async` before simply `cons`-ing it onto a list.  While kvb's solution certainly works, you could also do it with a `Seq.foldBack` like so:

```
module Async =
    let sequential s = 
        Seq.foldBack (fun cur acc -> async.Bind(cur, fun head -> 
            async.Bind(acc, fun tail -> async.Return(head :: tail)))) s (async.Return [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If one is willing to use the [AsyncSeq](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq/) library, then the following does what's needed in the given example:

```
async {
    let! results =
        myItems
        |> AsyncSeq.ofSeq
        |> AsyncSeq.mapAsync myAsynchronousOperation
        |> AsyncSeq.toListAsync

    ... do something with results
}
```

Probably overkill if you're not already using AsyncSeq for other things though.

Comment: I'm a big fan of `AsyncSeq`, and that is how I would probably handle this scenario in the real world.